# The Android app crashes when you to visit a meta site

Tags: bug, android-app

When getting to go to meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com the app crashes.

It also claimed that it was an "unknown site"

I reopened the app and clicked it again. It still crashed.

[[image: Unknown site[1]]

[image: The app crashed]

Comment: It's because meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com doesn't exist anymore (it's now codegolf.meta...), editing the site list should fix it, log out and in should fix any other issue with the site list